# Does a Dragonmark of Storm work with alchemical items?

Tags: dnd-4e, eberron, alchemy

If a player has a `Dragonmark of Storm`, which allows them to slide an enemy 1 square when they hit with a thunder or lightning power, will it work when they hit with appropriate alchemical items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

[Mark of Storms](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1397) doesn't specify that the power must be a power provided by your class or race. It would work even if you hit with a [Shock Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3120).

> Benefit: Whenever you hit an enemy with a thunder or lightning power, you can slide that enemy 1 square.

Comment: Thanks, good point on it not mentioning class or race.